# Is there a way to get a display port screen to ignore the screen being turned off?

Tags: resolution, displayport

We have some display port devices and when they are turned off they screw up the resolution of the display in VNC.

It is believed that the issue with this has to do with the display port connection that somehow informs the Win10 OS that the display is powered off, thus lowering the resolution.

Is there a standard way to disable this behavior or is it more likely a proprietary solution that's going to be different depending on the video card and driver?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not. DisplayPort is a smart connector. When you turn off a display, windows will uninstall the device, similar as how it happens with DVI.

There are some things you can try, but they are only succesful 5 out of 10 times, as in, some displays support it, others don't.

You can try to disable power saving features of the monitor.

Do note, this is how the connection protocol was designed. It is weird that it is, but its part of the plug and play functionality.

You can try to switch the monitor to a different display protocol (for example VGA/Sub-D), keep the monitor turned on, and let it go into standby. It should in theory keep the connection active and windows should not see a reason to uninstall the monitor.

Comment: Does Windows behave differently to Mac in this respect? On Mac, if a monitor is asleep or even manually switched to another input socket/protocol to force it to sleep/blank screen, it is still detected as being present. It only disappears from the OS if unplugged or physically switched off.

Comment: @Tetsujin Isn't that just what I wrote?